# Broken AVD system path - But ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined and correct?

Tags: android, android-emulator, continuous-integration, homebrew, continuous-deployment

I'm facing a really bizarre issue. I have a continuous integration service setup across a few identical machines locally. I just recently went to add a new machine to the cluster and I'm all of the sudden getting the `"PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/usr/local/share/android-sdk]!` error when this new machine tries to start an Android emulator.

The same install script to get a new instance online was used on all previous instances which are running fine.

The script installs the following dependencies (amongst others that are not related) via brew in order to run an Android emulator locally:

```
brew cask install java
brew cask install android-sdk
brew cask install android-platform-tools
brew cask install intel-haxm
```

Everything required is definitely in the `/usr/local/share/android-sdk` directory. The system-images, tools, platform-tools directories, etc.

I've done my own probing to try and figure this out. Additionally, I've checked the versions of the dependencies installed on this machine, and the version running on machines that are having no issues and they're the exact same...

I'm out of ideas on where to look.. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The environment variables are the same between both machines as well.

Note: These machines DO NOT install Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I didn't have everything installed:

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-27" "emulator"
```